# How to count the number of "correct" and "incorrect" responses

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to coding and am creating a windows form application in C#. I was having difficulties figuring out how to track the number of `correct` and `incorrect` responses. When a button is clicked, if the response is `correct` a label says correct. I want a different label to count the amount of times it says correct and incorrect. Here's what I was thinking but didn't work.

```
int add = 0;
add = int.Parse(correct.Text);

if (label1.Text == "Correct")
{
    correct.Text = add++;
}
else
    incorrect.text = add++;
```

`correct` and `incorrect` are names of my label.

Here's my button click event, there are many alike.

```
private void G_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (go.Visible == true)
            {
                go.Visible = false;
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int y = rnd.Next(1, 7);

                if (y == 1)
                {
                    eo.Visible = true;
                }
                if (y == 2)
                {
                    ao.Visible = true;
                }
                if (y == 4)
                {
                    dd.Visible = true;
                }
                if (y == 5)
                {
                    go.Visible = true;
                }
                if (y == 6)
                {
                    eeo.Visible = true;
                }

                timer1.Start();

                label1.Text = "Correct";
            }
            else
             {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
             }

            private int correctCount = 0;
            private int incorrectCount = 0;


             if (label1.Text = "Correct";)
                {
                     correctCount++;
                     correct.Text = correctCount.ToString();
                }
    else
                {
                      incorrectCount++;
                      incorrect.Text = incorrectCount.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: set breakpoints, single step through your code, compare expected values with actual values: what goes wrong?

Comment: `add++.ToString();` You must be getting an error, cannot convert `int` to `string`. This is just a fix not an answer to your question.

Comment: You need to debug you will get the answer .

Comment: @RahulSingh: That's not going to help - you're going to get the *existing* number as a string...

Comment: @CoderofCode: Currently it won't even compile. How would you expect to be able to debug?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes Sir, I was just pointing out the compiler error fix :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the type of the `Text` property is `string`, not `int` - you have to set it to *text*, not a number. Fortunately, you can just call `ToString` on an `int` to get a `string` representation. However, I'd suggest there are other things to change too.

I would strongly suggest that you keep separate counters as variables. While you *could* keep parsing your labels, it's simpler for them to be purely output. So you might have:

```
// Fields
private int correctCount = 0;
private int incorrectCount = 0;
...
// Wherever your code is
if (correctAnswer)
{
    correctCount++;
    correct.Text = correctCount.ToString();
}
else
{
    incorrectCount++;
    incorrect.Text = incorrectCount.ToString();
}
```

Note the `correctAnswer` condition here - we don't know what's setting the text of `label1`, but I'd suggest that that's the right place to *also* change the correct/incorrect counters, from the same condition. Again, treat `label1` just as output, rather than as a feedback system.

Comment: @HelpMe: I'm afraid I don't understand what I'm meant to do with that comment. If you've got multiple button click handlers which all do the same thing, you should consider just having *one* method which is the click handler for all relevant buttons...

Comment: I edited my main post, I tried your code but it doesn't work, didn't understand.

Comment: Sorry, I tried posting code but when I pressed enter to skip a line, the comment posted. I'm new to this >_<

Comment: @HelpMe: I said to introduce `correctCount` and `incorrectCount` as *fields* - you've got them as local variables. Do you understand the difference between the two? If you're very new to C#, I'd recommend learning the basics via console apps rather than GUIs - there's a lot less extra complexity to distract you from the language.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that comment. I moved the correctCount and incorrectCount. I tried to make my if statement if label1.Text = "correct" but it gives an error cannot convert string to bool. And yes, I'm very new to C#, I use both Windows Form and console

Comment: @HelpMe: Well look at what `label1.Text = "correct"` is doing. Is that comparing `label1.Text` with `"correct"` or is it assigning a new value?

Comment: @HelpMe What Jon means is that the "=" is not meant for comparing, you want to use "==" for that. And not to be harsh, but that is basic stuff, You should follow Jon's advice

Comment: Thank you for all the help, sorry for frustrating you all with my naiveness. I'll keep learning. It's just this was the last stage of basically completing my project.

Answer (score 0):

class fields = variables that are declared outside of a method and directly inside a class
local variables = variables that are declared inside of a method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace deleteMe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int correctCount = 0; // field

        private int incorrectCount = 0; // field

        private void G_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (go.Visible == true)
            {
                go.Visible = false;
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int y = rnd.Next(1, 7); // local variable

                if (y == 1)
                {
                    eo.Visible = true;
                }
                if (y == 2)
                {
                    ao.Visible = true;
                }
                if (y == 4)
                {
                    dd.Visible = true;
                }
                if (y == 5)
                {
                    go.Visible = true;
                }
                if (y == 6)
                {
                    eeo.Visible = true;
                }

                timer1.Start();

                incorrect.Text = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                incorrect.Text = "Incorrect";
            }


            if (label1.Text = "Correct")
            {
                correctCount++;
                correct.Text = correctCount.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                incorrectCount++;
                incorrect.Text = incorrectCount.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

==  equality. (for comparing 2 values)
= assign a value. (for initialize a variable or field)

Comment: Thank you, sorry I should've known.